# python - regex pattern is a large number of items, best practice?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a pro tip here.  I have in a database a list of strings, things like "MD", "PHD", "MR" etc.  various salutations.  It's several hundred rows and I receive it in a specific order (MD is more important than MR).  I also have a series of people objects that I'll be iterating and need a very efficient way of matching.  I've tried two and maybe there isn't another method.

My first try is when I receive the list, re.compile each one and put them into a list.  Then...

```
theregexlist = ["MR", "DR", "MRS" ... "MISS", "PHD"] #several hundred
personname = "MR JOEY SMITH" #other examples are similar like "BOBBY DR MD JOE"
for theregex in theregexlist:
    if re.search(theregex, personname):
        do stuffs....
        break #since my list is ordered, I only want the first match
```

Which does indeed work.  I also tried looping the regexlist and building a huge matching regex with capturing parans, re.compile it, and then:

```
hugeregex = re.compile("(?:(MR)|(MR)|(PHD)| ...  |(DR)|(MD))")
personname = "FRED DR FLINTSTONE"
maybematch = re.search(hugeregex, personname)
if maybematch:
    print (maybematch.group(0))
```

Is there some kind of map, leverage keys, or iteration function that I'm just not thinking of that would be more efficient?  Any and all idea are appreciated!  Even if it's "Yup, it's just gonna be slow, try to use timeit to see which is faster", then I can stop searching :)  Thank you!

Comment: thank you! added some examples

Comment: Youre RegEx can match inside a name. You ought to add more constraints, like: `r"\b(?:MR|MR|PHD| ...  |DR|MD)\b"`: begin of word + any particule + end of word.

Comment: Ah yes, the production code does use word boundaries.  Just keeping it simple for the sake of this question :)

Comment: You would prefer your second method;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "big" RegEx with all "particules" (like "MR", "MS", etc.), will be more efficient because it will be compiled only once. And you reduce function calls (which is an optimisation).

If you have special characters inside a particule, you may need to escape them with `re.escape`.

You can compile the RegEx and get a reference to the `search` method.

Here is an example:

```
import re

particules = ["MR", "DR", "MRS", "MISS", "PHD"]

regex = r"\b(?:" + "|".join(map(re.escape, particules)) + r")\b"
search_any_particule = re.compile(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

personname = "FRED DR FLINTSTONE"

mo = search_any_particule(personname)
if mo:
    print(mo.group())
```

You get: 'DR'.

**EDIT**

The best way to make sure you implementation is efficient is to **profile** it. For that, you can use `cProfile` library.

For instance:

```
def find_particule(personname):
    mo = search_any_particule(personname)
    if mo:
        return mo.group()
    return None

import cProfile

cProfile.runctx('for i in range(1000000): find_particule("FRED DR FLINTSTONE")', globals(), locals())
```

The profiler will give you something like this:

```
         3000003 function calls in 2.110 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.353    0.353    2.110    2.110 <string>:1(<module>)
  1000000    0.495    0.000    1.757    0.000 python:10(find_particule)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.110    2.110 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1000000    0.185    0.000    0.185    0.000 {method 'group' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
  1000000    1.078    0.000    1.078    0.000 {method 'search' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
```

Comment: Excellent feedback.  I'll make sure to have compiles in place.  Interestingly enough, mProfile is how I found this to be the slow part of my code! :)  Are there other ways besides making one big regex or a for loop of compiled regexes I should be trying?

Comment: I experienced much more complex RegEx than yours, and I'm sure it's the best choice, even on very big input (several Mo). Python RegEx are great!

Comment: One other way is to use your own char-by-char parser (a state machine), it could be efficient for your use case but really hard to maintain. There are other alternative, like [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) or [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) (grammar parser like lex & yacc) but they both generate Python code which will be less efficient… and too complex.